# How do I erase part of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

If my std::vector has 1890 elements, and I want to keep the first 1000 and erase the rest,and then again next 890 elements and erase the first 1000,.. so a loop seems to be necessary.
Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: @claptrap: check the edit history; this used to be a completely different question.

Comment: What does mean phrase "and then again next 890 elements"?!

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` has an `erase` member function that allows you to erase a range of elements without using an explicit loop. For example:

```
std::vector<whatever> x(1890);

// erase first 1000 items
x.erase(x.begin(), x.begin()+1000);
```

Comment: @Bhargava: That is an entirely different question.